# How to create jenkinsfile that supports ansiColors but also executes on jenkins host that does not have ansiColors installed

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have added ansiColors to a Jenkinsfile that is used on multiple jenkins hosts following
[Jenkins pipeline ansicolor console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198890/jenkins-pipeline-ansicolor-console-output)

Unfortunately, not all jenkins hosts have the AnsiColor plugin installed.
On hosts where the plugin is not installed, I get an error

```
Started by upstream project "**********************" build number 450
originally caused by:
 Started by timer
Obtained ............../Jenkinsfile from git https://host:/repo.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'ansiColor' found among steps [
```

Is there a way to code the jenkinsfile so that it will use ansiColors when available but still execute when the plugin is missing.

My, trimmed, Jenkinsfile

```
ansiColor('xterm') {    
    withFolderProperties{

        env.getEnvironment()

        def nodelabel
        try{ nodelabel="${env.CCEBUILD_NODE}" } catch (e) { }
        if (nodelabel == "null" || nodelabel == null) { nodelabel = "devts" }

// trimmed

        node("${nodelabel}") {

            stage('Info') {
                dir("${applroot}") {
                    callAnt(antbaseparameters, "info")
                }
            }

// trimmed

        } // node("${nodelabel}")

    } // withFolderProperties
} // ansiColor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your code into a function and do something like this:

```
def doSomthing(){
    withFolderProperties{ ... }
}

try {
    ansiColor('xterm') {
       doSomthing() 
    }
} catch (NoSuchMethodError e){
    doSomthing()
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but wouldn't that cause a 2nd execution of doSomthing if that fails

Comment: why? after failing to run `ansiColor` the try block breaks and skip to the catch block it's not getting to the first `doSomthing()`